# Can I use OAuth for authentication for trusted client (mobile app)?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I know how OAuth2 and OpenID Connect works. But there is still some confusion bothering me.

We develop our own Auth Server, service API and mobile app. So, the client app is trusted and we use "password" grant type. The app user repository follows the same user database in auth server.

Our customers login to the app by username/password. The app then submits the user credential to the Auth Server token endpoint, which will return the (bearer) access token and ID token (JWT) to the client.
The ID token contains basic user information so that the app can greet user like "Welcome Tony Stark!".
The access token can be used to access API (e.g. update user profile).

OAuth by design is not a tool for authentication. Ref: https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/OAuth-is-Not-Authentication

My questions are

1) Do we need to verify the signature of the ID token if the client only is only interested to get the user information? Also note that the ID token is coming from the token endpoint via https connection.

2) Let's forget about the ID token. Can we treat the user has passed the authentication check (i.e. login success) if the client obtains an access token from the Auth Server? This flow is very similar to simple password login without OAuth.

3) The client can access protected APIs with the access token. Without access token, the client can only invoke some public APIs. Is it equivalent to what can be done with and without login? It seems the access token can be treated as "login session cookie".

4) There is no 3rd party involvement in my case. Everything (client, auth server, service API) is developed and owned by the same organization. Does it still make sense to use OAuth?

Answer (score 1):

Typically a mobile app is considered a public client. Unless you're limiting who has access to the mobile app, it can't be considered trusted as someone could mess with the app outside of your control even if you developed it.

Also, the resource credentials grant type is generally not a good idea.
One thing is that the OpenID Connect spec requires authorization code, id token, or a hybrid flow:

> Authentication can follow one of three paths: the Authorization Code
> Flow (response_type=code), the Implicit Flow (response_type=id_token
> token or response_type=id_token), or the Hybrid Flow (using other
> Response Type values defined in OAuth 2.0 Multiple Response Type
> Encoding Practices [OAuth.Responses]).

Some other reasons:
[Why the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Type is not Authentication nor Suitable for Modern Applications](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications)

1. The OpenID Connect RFC says you MUST verify the ID token:

> When using the Implicit Flow, the contents of the ID Token MUST be validated in the same manner as for the Authorization Code Flow, as defined in Section 3.1.3.7, with the exception of the differences specified in this section.

Although, you may qualify for this exception from 3.1.3.7 if using TLS:

> If the ID Token is received via direct communication between the Client and the Token Endpoint (which it is in this flow), the TLS server validation MAY be used to validate the issuer in place of checking the token signature. The Client MUST validate the signature of all other ID Tokens according to JWS [JWS] using the algorithm specified in the JWT alg Header Parameter. The Client MUST use the keys provided by the Issuer.

2. If you're able to trust the client, and the user/pass check you've implemented, then you should be able to trust that an access token has been granted to an authenticated identity according to the OAuth 2.0 spec.
3. The access token in OAuth 2.0 also contains scopes and should limit what can be done with that access token. A login without OAuth doesn't necessarily.
4. It's a good idea to use OAuth to protect the credentials of the resource owner. If you were to use the resource owner credentials grant type, this still provides some benefits as the user could enter the password only when the client doesn't have a valid access token, ie, the user can enter her password once for an access token and validate the user using that instead of entering the password again or storing it somewhere.

> Even though this grant type requires direct client access to the
> resource owner credentials, the resource owner credentials are used
> for a single request and are exchanged for an access token.  This
> grant type can eliminate the need for the client to store the
> resource owner credentials for future use, by exchanging the
> credentials with a long-lived access token or refresh token.

[OAuth 2.0 RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1)

Comment: "Unless you're limiting who has access to the mobile app, it can't be considered trusted as someone could mess with the app."    Why? Do you assume those who has access are trusted and would not mess up the app?

Comment: For point 3. We don't have consent page to show the scope to the user. We would simply use a "default" scope that can access all server APIs. So, we have only two categories i) protected API (token required) ii) anonymous public API (no token required). I cannot see the advantage of defining a few more scope in my case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking in the first comment. I was saying you _can't_ assume those who have access to the app are trusted.

Comment: For Point 3. In your case then, OAuth doesn't really provide any benefit over a regular login, but point 4 provides some other benefits of using OAuth 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Do we need to verify the signature of the ID token if the client
>   only is only interested to get the user information? Also note that
>   the ID token is coming from the token endpoint via https connection.

YES.

> 2) Let's forget about the ID token. Can we treat the user has passed
>   the authentication check (i.e. login success) if the client obtains an
>   access token from the Auth Server? This flow is very similar to simple
>   password login without OAuth.

If I understand the premise. Yes..There is no requirement for using the ID Token.

> 3) The client can access protected APIs with the access token. Without
>   access token, the client can only invoke some public APIs. Is it
>   equivalent to what can be done with and without login? It seems the
>   access token can be treated as "login session cookie".

The access token is a access (like a key) that for the OAuth Client to use that was delegated permissions from the resource owner.

> 4) There is no 3rd party involvement in my case. Everything (client,
>   auth server, service API) is developed and owned by the same
>   organization. Does it still make sense to use OAuth?

Yes. OAuth and OpenID Connect are used by many, many organizations and is a test solution.

You should not try to re-invent the "wheel". Use known trusted libraries for Authentication, Authorization and cryptographic operations. [OpenID Connect has some certified Implementations](https://openid.net/developers/certified/)